# Using ROS with Kinect (Failed to set USB interface)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to use ROS with Kinect.

```
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart
```

This tutorial says it is as easy as plug in Kinect to USB and launch

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

But I get

```
process[camera_base_link3-21]: started with pid [32556]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-camera-1.8.6/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-camera/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Failed to set USB interface!

[camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 31934, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=...
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

lsusb shows

```
Bus 002 Device 019: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55201/using-ros-with-kinect-(failed-to-set-usb-interface)/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found answer here:

http://blog.jozilla.net/2012/03/29/getting-up-and-running-with-the-kinect-in-ubuntu-12-04/

```
$ sudo modprobe -r gspca_kinect 
$ sudo modprobe -r gspca_main
```

---

Originally posted by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) with karma: 212 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blairlpp](https://answers.ros.org/users/26966/blairlpp/) on 2016-06-11**:
hello, the link u gave us is unavailable, could u please give us another one cause i tried the two sudo command below but it doesn't work. thanks a lot~